# sort seems to crash without indication

Tags: process, sort, crash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this applies more to Unix generally than to Apache Jena or to the Windows Subsystem for Linux - after all, it's the `sort` utility that seems to vanish without a log.

I'm following the process detailed [here](https://muncca.com/2019/02/14/wikidata-import-in-apache-jena/) to import Wikidata in a local Apache Jena instance. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10's Subsystem for Linux.

The data phase (data import) worked fine, but the index phase ([see here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/commands.html#tdbloader2)) always crashes without notice. Here are the details:

I'm running this script in bash (after `--phase data` completed successfully):

```
apache-jena-3.15.0/bin/tdbloader2 --phase index --loc data/  > tdb1.log 2> tdb2.log &
```

This writes the following four log entries into tdb1.log:

```
 12:09:02 INFO -- TDB Bulk Loader Start
 12:09:02 INFO Index Building Phase
 12:09:02 INFO Creating Index SPO
 12:09:02 INFO Sort SPO
```

This script uses `sort` internally. Indeed, a process named `sort` runs for about 20 minutes, using about 15 GB of memory. After that time, the process disappears without notice and without an additional log.

My question is, how can I find the reason for the crash? Shouldn't `sort` write some sort of crash indication or post-mortem?

If it helps, the [Jena Documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/commands.html#tdbloader2) says

> The indexing phase of the build uses the sort utility to prepare the
>   raw data for indexing, this can potentially require large amounts of
>   disk space and the scripts will automatically check and warn/abort if
>   the disk space looks to be/is insufficient.

Where do I see this warning? And no, the free disk space is over 100 GB, so I don't see this as an immediate reason.

Comment: What makes you think there is a crash? It sounds like sort finished, produced a sorted file and exited. Tools don't randomly produce log files! That would just be a waste of space. Imagine if `sort` produced a log file every time it was run! You'd run out of disk space in a week.

Comment: @terdon In the data phase of the import, the TDB bulk loader wrote a log message which indicated that the process has finished successfully. In the index phase, the one which runs `sort`, I don't see such a message. See the four log statements in my question. After the `sort` process vanishes, the `tdb1.log` file is not continued, so there must be a problem at this step. But you're right, the problem might be in `tdbloader2` and not in `sort`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some more details. We need to know what makes you think the process crashed, what commands were run, what output was generated, what output _should_ have been generated instead. By the way, any errors would be in `tbd2.log`, not `tbd1.log`. Anything there?

Comment: @terdon I ran it again and this time indeed there is an error in `tdb2.log` ("No space left on device"). No idea why this wasn't there the first time. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Ah, great. Could you please post that as an answer so the question can be marked as answered?

Comment: @terdon done, completed

Comment: The "No space left on device" message possibly was not logged because there was no space left on device. Picking up that last free block is something of a lottery.

Answer (score 1):

Found the error in the `tdb2.log` output (the one with the `2>` pipe operator).

Turns out `sort` ran out of disk space.